# SKLabel is not showing when it's assigned to a specific element

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground, sklabelnode

(All the following code has been written in Swift Playgrounds)

First I added 3 variables and put those in an array

```
var rnaBacteriaCopy1 = SKSpriteNode()
var rnaBacteriaCopy2 = SKSpriteNode()
var rnaVirusCopy4 = SKSpriteNode()

let rnaCopies = [
rnaBacteriaCopy1,rnaVirusCopy4,rnaBacteriaCopy2
]
```

Then I assigned SKTextures to those variables (text is similar for each of them)

```
rnaBacteriaCopy1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image:(here I inserted a PNG))
        
rnaBacteriaCopy1.position = CGPoint(x: 1160, y: 325)
       
 rnaBacteriaCopy1.isHidden = true 
       
 addChild(rnaBacteriaCopy1)
```

Lastly with the `public override function touches began` I made it pick a random variable and if the variable picked was a specific one, display the label.

```
override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        var therandomCopy = rnaCopies.randomElement()
        rnaCopies.randomElement()?.isHidden = false 
if therandomCopy == rnaBacteriaCopy1 {
            // Fading Label
            var tryAgainLbl = SKLabelNode(text: "Uh oh! Try again.")
            tryAgainLbl.fontSize = 70.0 
            tryAgainLbl.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
            tryAgainLbl.fontColor = .white
            
            let fadein = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1)
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            tryAgainLbl.run(SKAction.sequence([fadein,remove]))
            addChild(tryAgainLbl)
            //Hide this copy 
            rnaCopies.randomElement()?.isHidden = false 
            rnaCopies.randomElement()?.isHidden = true 
        }
```

At the end I made the random element hide, so you could see other SKTexture and click on it. I already tried making the if statements as specific as possible `(putting && != to other variable other than this)`. But it doesn't work, any ideas why?

Comment: The label code works when run on its own. Therefore I would add in a print("this works") in the Fading Label code. If it never prints then you know it is the "therandomCopy == rnaBacteriaCopy1" which is the issue. If it does print, then maybe increase the "tryAgainLbl" zposition as it could be hidden behind other objects. I do not know what "therandomCopy" is, are you comparing 2 spritenodes to each other with ==?

Comment: Ah sorry! I forgot to add the code in the original post. therandomCopy is a variable containing a random element from the array

Answer (score 0):

Give the nodes names, this is so you can reference them.

You can set the name where you set the position and isHidden etc..

```
rnaBacteriaCopy1.name = "bacteria1"
```

To note, you can give the same name to more than 1 node, so if it makes sense for all of your bacteria nodes to have the name "bacteria", then you can do that.

You can provide the virus a name also:

```
rnaVirusCopy4.name = "virus"
```

Now, in your touches began replace this code:

```
if therandomCopy == rnaBacteriaCopy1 {
```

With this:

```
if therandomCopy.name == "bacteria1" {
```

This means if the randomCopy node has the name "bacteria1" then proceed with the label code inside the if.

Comment: This solution didn't quite work well for me (not sure why). I'll try comparing therandomCopy to the texture the node has. Maybe that'll work? Thanks for the help anyway @JohnL :)